# Что я хочу сделать – так это

Tags: пунктуация

Можете сказать, какой вариант корректный таки?

1. Что я хочу сделать – так это найти мой спиннинг.
2. Что я хочу сделать, так это найти мой спиннинг.
3. Что я хочу сделать: так это найти мой спиннинг.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Основной вариант: ***Что** я хочу сделать, **так это** найти мой спиннинг.*

Вариант с интонационным тире: ***Что** я хочу сделать – **так это** найти мой спиннинг.*

**Пояснение**

Это **вопрос-ответная** модель предложения. Вопрос-ответ построен на основе местоименной связи (***что – так это***) и изъяснительной связи.

Фразеологизованная модель вопрос-ответного предложения строится так:

**Вопрос:** Что я хочу сделать? **Ответ**: Я хочу найти мой спиннинг.

**Вопрос-ответ**: Что я хочу сделать, так это найти мой спиннинг.