# То, что мне надо (сделать, / сделать, —) так это погулять

Tags: пунктуация

Тире с запятой или запятая?

> То, что мне надо сделать, так это погулять.

> То, что мне надо сделать, — так это погулять.

Comment: Пишите по-русски, please :  Что  я хочу сделать, так это погулять.  Повтор вопроса:  https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/475489/Что-я-хочу-сделать-так-это/475494#475494

Comment: А главное, эта стилизованная не знаю подо что  речь уже надоела, Скорее всего, она стилизована под неграмотность. КОНВЕЙЕР низкокачественных вопросов и ответов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Верно с запятой:

*То, что мне надо сделать, так это погулять*.

**[«Грамота.ру»](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=285952)**:

> Единственное, что он хотел, (-) так это выпить и закусить. Нужно ли тире в данном случае?
>
> ---
>
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>
> Тире не требуется: *Единственное, что он хотел, так это выпить и закусить*.

Абсолютно аналогичный вариант: такая же структура + присутствует подлежащее (у вас — *то*, у «Грамоты» — *единственное*).

Comment: Максим, вы же говорили, что Грамоте не во всём нужно верить. А она не даёт никаких объяснений. Почему не ставится тире между подлежащим и сказуемым?

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец _Не во всëм_ не значит _вообще нельзя_. Про паузу в ответе потом скажу, дополню, а пока времени маловато.

Comment: Разве я сказал "вообще нельзя"? Написал так, как вы писали.